# Capturing a repeated group vs repeating a capturing group in the middle of a complex regex

Tags: regex, pcre

First: [I](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24936169/repeating-a-capturing-group-vs-capturing-a-repeated-group) [know](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29606006/repeating-a-capturing-group-vs-capturing-a-repeated-group-with-nested-pattern) [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25561/capturing-a-repeated-group) [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17425526/capturing-a-repeated-group-with-reference) [has](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39155242/regex-not-matching-due-to-repeated-capturing-group-rather-than-capturing-a-repea) [been](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3133145/regular-expression-capturing-a-repeated-group) [beaten](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33349988/repeating-a-capturing-group) [to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42369864/capturing-a-specific-repeated-group) [death.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33989116/capture-section-of-a-repeating-regex-capture-group)

Second: I've looked at every resource (online editors, [RexEgg](http://www.rexegg.com/), [regular-expressions.info](http://regular-expressions.info) etc...) I can think of over the past few years and I still cannot grasp this part of regex. It never seems to work for me no matter what RegEx I use.

Now that the house-keeping is out of the way:

I have a large amount of text that I need to extract some data from that I think Regex is well-suited for.

The text looks like this:

> 2017-03-31 09:41:18 EDT [12708-4] parameters: $1 = '0', $2 = 'ON', $3 = 'ON'

Fairly obviously, I want the values for `$1`, `$2` and `$3`. This particular example has 3 variables but it's generally between 1 and 15.

I want a regex that will capture the following:

1. $1
2. '0'
3. $2
4. 'ON'
5. $3
6. 'ON'

This is my regex, which matches the first group:

`\d{4}.+\[[\d-]*\].+?parameters:\s((\$\d+)\s?=\s?(['\d+\w+]+))`

but no combination of pluses, parentheses and commas produces anything near what I want. Even if I remove the commas from the string and just jam them together I can't get it to capture.

This guy captures everything, but the groups don't make sense:

`\d{4}.+\[[\d-]*\].+?parameters:\s(((\$\d+)\s?=\s?(['\d+\w+]+),?\s?)+)`

Can someone end my misery here and explain to me how to capture repeated text in a regex if the text is separated by characters that I don't care about?

Comment: You might want to take a look at `\G` which matches at the position, the previous match ended. `(?:\G(?!^),|parameters:)\s+(\$\d+) = '(\w+)'` should be somewhat what you are looking for.

Comment: I couldn't get that one to work either. Still only captured one

Comment: Try multiple matching/capturing Sebastian mentions with a bit modified pattern: [`(?:\G(?!^),|parameters:)\s*(\$\d+)\s*=\s*'([^']+)'\s*`](https://regex101.com/r/3nHI53/1). It won't give you 6 groups, because there can only be as many groups as there are defined in the pattern. It will give 3 matches x 2 groups in each. If this approach is not what you need, you just cannot get it with pure regex. What is the programming language?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use come regex to extract each value set like this `(\$\d) = '(.+?)'` [example](https://regex101.com/r/YY0KRD/1)

Then you can loop through all the matches. Group 1 will be the label (ie. $1) and Group 2 will be the value (ie. 0)

Just a small warning I think is worth mentioning: "A repeated capturing group will only capture the last iteration. Put a capturing group around the repeated group to capture all iterations or use a non-capturing group instead if you're not interested in the data" (as noted on [regex101](http://regex101.com))

Comment: There's a lot more unrelated stuff to the problem that prevents me from just capturing the two groups separately. I'm aware that it will only capture the last iteration. I tried getting around it by putting a capturing group around the repeated group but it didn't work.